# QUnit not found

Tags: javascript, qunit

I have the following code in javascript, call persona.js:

```
var PrototipoPersona = {
         nombre : '' ,
         primerApellido : '',
         segundoApellido : ''
    }
    getNombre = function(){
        return this.nombre;
    }
    getPrimerApellido = function(){
        return this.primerApellido;
    }
    getSegundoApellido = function(){
        return this.segundoApellido;
    }

    setNombre = function(nombre){
        this.nombre=nombre;
    }
    setPrimerApellido = function(primerApellido){
        this.primerApellido = primerApellido;
    }
    setSegundoApellido = function(segundoApellido)
    {
        this.segundoApellido = segundoApellido;
    }
    var Persona = function(datosPersona) {
       var miPersona = Object.create(PrototipoPersona);
       miPersona = $.extend(miPersona,datosPersona);
       return miPersona;
    }
```

a controler call controlador.js:

```
$(document).on('ready',function(){

    var datosPersona = {
        nombre : 'Juan' ,
        primerApellido : 'Garcia',
        segundoApellido : 'Lopez'
   };
   var miPersona = Persona(datosPersona);
   var nombre = miPersona.getNombre();
   var primerApellido = miPersona.getPrimerApellido();
   var segundoApellido = miPersona.getSegundoApellido();
   QUnit.test("prueba", function(assert) {  
     assert.equal(nombre,"Juan","El nombre es correcto");
     assert.equal(primerApellido,"Garcia","El primer apellido es correcto");
     assert.equal(segundoApellido,"Lopez", "El segundo apellido es correcto");
   });
});
```

and index.html:

```
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Ejemplo basico de javascript</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="qunit-2.9.2.css">
<script src="./qunit-2.9.2.js"></script>
<script src="./jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js"></script>
<script src="./controlador.js"></script>
<script src="./persona.js"></script>
</head>
 <body>
     <div id="qunit"></div>
     <div id="qunit-fixture"></div>    
 </body>
</html>
```

[image: Output in Browser]

When I try the following code it doesn't work, it gives the error shown in the image, because it doesn't work when I run it in the browser Qunit can't find the tests to start, I'm using mozilla firefox and visual studio code but I don't think that's the problem

Comment: ```controlador.js``` is calling methods in ```persona.js``` but in your html ```persona.js``` script is loaded after the ```controlador.js```. Could you try moving ```<script src="./controlador.js"></script>``` after the ```persona.js``` ```<script></script>``` tag?

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that QUnit *also* runs on document ready, and YOUR document.ready is running *after* its document.ready. So, your tests (in controlador.js) don't exist yet. Instead, reorder the HTML file with the JS files at the end, and in the order suggested in the comment above (persona *before* controlador), and then remove the document.ready for your code.

Here is an [example in JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/w98L67cz/) that "works" in that it runs QUnit. You have other problems in your code, but hopefully the running test will help.

In the html file:

```
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Ejemplo basico de javascript</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="qunit-2.9.2.css">
</head>
 <body>
     <div id="qunit"></div>
     <div id="qunit-fixture"></div>

     <script src="./jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js"></script> <!-- put jQuery first! -->
     <script src="./qunit-2.9.2.js"></script>
     <script src="./persona.js"></script>   <!-- notice this one BEFORE controlador -->
     <script src="./controlador.js"></script>
 </body>
</html>
```

Then in `controlador.js`:

```
QUnit.test("prueba", function(assert) {
  // Note that I moved all test code INSIDE the test case, this is the proper way.
  var datosPersona = {
    nombre : 'Juan' ,
    primerApellido : 'Garcia',
    segundoApellido : 'Lopez'
  };
  var miPersona = Persona(datosPersona);
  var nombre = miPersona.getNombre();
  var primerApellido = miPersona.getPrimerApellido();
  var segundoApellido = miPersona.getSegundoApellido();

  assert.equal(nombre,"Juan","El nombre es correcto");
  assert.equal(primerApellido,"Garcia","El primer apellido es correcto");
  assert.equal(segundoApellido,"Lopez", "El segundo apellido es correcto");
});
```